# Why is .nextAll() not returning the expected elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm pretty new to Javascript/jQuery. Just trying to understand what is going wrong with the following code?:

Javascript:

```
$('.rating-stars').each(function() {
    var currentScore = $(this).nextAll('.current-score');
    console.log(currentScore);
    $('.rating-stars').barrating('show', {
        theme: 'fontawesome-stars-o',
        deselectable: false,
        showSelectedRating: false,
        initialRating: currentScore,
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="vote_form" class="form-inline" method="post" action="/y/update_rating/39">

  <span class="h3"><a href="#">Title</a></span>             

    <select class="rating-stars" id="id_vote" name="vote">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1"></option>
      <option value="2"></option>
      <option value="3"></option>
      <option value="4"></option>
      <option value="5"></option>
    </select>

  <span class="current-score">4.0</span>

</form>
```

In short, I have an element with the class .rating-stars an element with the class .current-score **next to it** that displays a score/integer.

I want to set the initialRating to be the number displayed by the .current-score element.

(as you can probably guess by the code, there is more than 1 rating displayed on the page, hence the .each function)

Currently, that `console.log` is returning:

> [select#id_vote.rating-stars, context: select#id_vote.rating-stars]0: select#id_vote.rating-starscontext: select#id_vote.rating-starslength: 1__proto__: Object[0]
>   ratings.js:7 [select#id_vote.rating-stars, context: select#id_vote.rating-stars]

Comment: Pls share you code on jsfiddle.net

Comment: not a valid markup and it's not a ssibling

Comment: `.nextAll()` works on *sibling* elements. Your `.rating-stars` element has no siblings. I can't suggest an alternative, because your html as shown is incomplete/invalid on its own. Please [edit] your question to show clearly how the `.current-score` span is related to the tr with the select - where is the table that the tr belongs to?

Comment: I've fixed my HTML.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you want when you say use jsfiddle? Do you want me to copy/paste the above html/js?

Comment: the return value of `nextAll` is an array of jQuery objects.  You need to get the text content of the first element in the array (if, as you say there are going to be multiple `rating-stars` elements), more like `var currentScore = $(this).nextAll('.current-score').first().html()`

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the comments on my answer I have come up with a solution:

I was misunderstanding .next() — I didn't realize it only looked for siblings, I thought it actually read through everything top to bottom, not in a hierarchical fashion.

I simply needed to add .parent() to my variable before the .next or .nextAll call:

```
var currentScore = $(this).parent().next('.current-score').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This -

`HTML`

```
<form id="vote_form" class="form-inline" method="post" action="/y/update_rating/39">

  <span class="h3"><a href="#">Title</a></span>             

    <select class="rating-stars" id="id_vote" name="vote">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>

  <span class="current-score">3.0</span>

</form>
```

`Jquery`

```
$('.rating-stars').each(function() {
    var currentScore = $(this).next('.current-score').text();
    console.log(currentScore);
    $(this).barrating('show', {
        theme: 'fontawesome-stars-o',
        deselectable: false,
        showSelectedRating: false,
        initialRating: currentScore,        
    });
});
```

Link to [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/uwp7x5ou/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case `.next()` will works :

> Note: Your are trying to get element but you need to get element html
>   or text.

```
$('.rating-stars').each(function() {
    var currentScore = $(this).next('.current-score').html();
    console.log(currentScore);
    $('.rating-stars').barrating('show', {
        theme: 'fontawesome-stars-o',
        deselectable: false,
        showSelectedRating: false,
        initialRating: currentScore,
    });
});
```